# How do I access float's name (e.g. for use with caption*)?

Tags: floats, captions, naming

I would like to access the current name of the float.

In the [float package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/float) manual, I've read that command `\floatname{<float name>}{<new name>}` works by redefining `\fname@<float name>`. However, I wasn't able to get it working

Here is an example of what I would like to achieve:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\floatname{algorithm}{New name for algorithm}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}

Some algorithm here.

\caption{This is a caption where I would like to reference the float name (i.e. ``New name for algorithm'').}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name is stored in `\fname@algorithm`, so it's easy to obtain a user level command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\floatname{algorithm}{New name for algorithm}
\makeatletter
\let\algorithmname\fname@algorithm
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}

Some algorithm here.

\caption{This is a caption where I would like to reference the float name
which is ``\algorithmname''}

\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]